# filter eloquent models in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have different filters for every category in my blade. when l click on every filter, page URL changes and filter name and filter value shows in URL, like this:

> 127.0.0.1:8000/categories/search/9?brand[1]=Samsung&brand[2]=Sony&system=android

As you see,every filter can be string or array.
How can I get every filter name in my controller and filter products based on filter name and filter value?
I wrote this conditions ,but these conditions only work if filters that are string, and I don't know how can I write conditions for array filters. This is my controller:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Category;
use App\Filter;
use App\product;
use App\ProductQa;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $q = product::query();
        if ($request->has('brand')) {
            $q->where('brand', '=', $request->get('brand'));
        }
        if ($request->has('system')) {
            $q->where('system', '=', $request->get('system'));
        }
        return $q;

    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good time to use eloquents `whereIn` method. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses, see the section on whereIn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can use `whereIn` to search with an array of data.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $q = product::query();

    if ($request->has('brand')) {
        $q->whereIn('brand', (array) $request->input('brand'));
    }

    if ($request->has('system')) {
        $q->whereIn('system', (array) $request->input('system'));
    }

    ...

    return $q->get();
}
```

Casting the input to array, `(array)`, allows us to use only `whereIn`. If it is already an array you are good and if it is a string it is now in an array. You can also check for an array or a string and use `where` or `whereIn` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

First define set of filter parameters with their column names, if the filter is array then apply `whereIn` function else apply `where` function

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $q = product::query();
        // ['columnName'=>'GetParamName']
        $filters = ['brand'=>'brand','system'=>'system'];
        foreach($filters as $column => $key){
            if ($request->has($key)) {
                $filterVal = $request->input($key)
                if(is_array($filterVal)){
                  $q->whereIn($column, $filterVal);
                }else{
                  $q->where($column,'=', $filterVal);
                }
            }
        }

        return $q;

    }
```